# Swift inheritance issues

Tags: ios, class, swift

```
class Foo {
  var str = "hi";

  func refresh() {
    println(self.str);
  }
}

class Bar: Foo {
  // override str in init
  // create Zed with parent = self
}

class Baz: Foo {
  // override str in init
  // create Zed with parent = self
}


class Zed {
  var parent: Foo?; // I want it to work for both Bar and Baz

  // call parent.refresh() in init
}
```

I want class Zed to have a property that works for both classes Bar and Baz. Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to access `parent` from the Bar and Baz classes?

Comment: `parent` should be either the `Bar` or `Baz` class.

Comment: So what's not working? That looks fine to me...

Comment: Whatever doesn't work, the problem is not in this code. And setting str in init of Bar or Baz isn't a problem either. Because according to my Playground that works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the issue, because this code looks fine to me:

```
class Foo {
    var str = "hi";

    func refresh() {
        println(self.str);
    }
}

class Bar: Foo {
    override init () {
        super.init()
        str = "bar"
        let zed = Zed(parent: self)
    }
}

class Baz: Foo {
    override init () {
        super.init()
        str = "baz"
        let zed = Zed(parent: self)
    }
}


class Zed {
    var parent: Foo?; // I want it to work for both Bar and Baz

    init(parent: Foo) {
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent?.refresh()
    }
}

let b = Bar() // prints bar

let c = Baz() // prints baz
```

If the question is how to make sure no other subclasses of Foo are allowed to be Zed's parents: there is no way to specify an "or" constraint in Swift's type constraints, but you can adopt the same protocol in Bar and Baz and specify that protocol as `parent`'s type:

```
protocol CanRefresh
{
    func refresh()
}

extension Bar : CanRefresh
{

}

extension Baz : CanRefresh
{

}

class Zed {
    var parent: CanRefresh?; // I want it to work for both Bar and Baz

    init(parent: CanRefresh) {
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent?.refresh()
    }
}
```

This way you can explicitly list the classes that Zed supports (but it's a pretty bad API design ;  you should publish the protocol instead and let anyone who desires to do it conform to that protocol).

Comment: I guess I had another issue. I cleaned up the code and it worked as expected, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The closest that I could think of is using a [Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html) for the parent class.

```
protocol FooProtocol {
  var str: String { get set }
  func refresh()
}

class Foo {
  var str = "hi"

  func refresh() {
    println(self.str)
  }
}
```

Foo now conforms to the *FooProtocol*, even though it doesn't directly implement it. This way, every class that inherits from Foo, also conforms to the protocol.

```
class Bar: Foo, FooProtocol {
  override init() {
    super.init()
    self.str = "ho"
  }
}

class Baz: Foo, FooProtocol {
  override init() {
    super.init()
    self.str = "hup"
  }
}
```

Now you should be able, to set the type of `parent` in Zed to `FooProtocol`. It could then be an instance of either Bar or Baz.

```
class Zed {
  var parent: FooProtocol?
}
```

Comment: Isn't it pretty useless to create a protocol for the parent class if you subclass the parent anyway?

Comment: It's not, if you don't want to implement `refresh()` in every single subclass.

Comment: You don't have to reimplement it in every subclass! Bar and Baz inherit it from foo even if there is no protocol involved, and inheriting from Foo is a sufficient type constraint. In other words, the code in the question is sufficient. I suspect the actual question is how to prevent other subclasses of Foo to be used as `parent`, in which case using a protocol like this is a solution.

Comment: If you don't implement `refresh()` in the subclass, that class does not conform to a protocol that requires `refresh()`. But that's not what you do. You subclass a class that conforms to a protocol. It might make sense to replace `class Bar: Foo` with `class Bar: FooProtocol`, but in your example it's pointless.

Comment: Bar and Baz inherit from Foo, which already implements `refresh()`. That's why I can access this method, and also why it conforms to `FooProtocol`. It worked in my playground. A change could be to not implement the Protocol in Foo, but instead in Bar and Baz only. That way, you couldn't get an instance of `Foo` to fit into parent.